# Can more options be added for flagging for migration?

Tags: support, feature-request, migration

I review posts in the queue, and I am often am flagging some posts. I will sometimes flag posts as those that need to be closed because they are off-topic, but this is the only option available:

---

[image]

---

Obviously there are many other SE website where questions could potentially belong. These include Medical Sciences.SE, Psychology.SE, Bioinformatics.SE, and Chemistry.SE.

Can these options be added?

Comment: See https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/464/how-to-migrate-a-question-to-another-se

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't, please flag it accordingly for the mods.

Comment: Related: [Why can't I select any site I want when I vote to close a question](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/621/16866)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal users [can only vote to migrate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258593/do-the-new-graduation-policies-have-any-effect-on-migrations-to-beta-sites?r=SearchResults) to sites which have graduated, but moderators can.

Out of your examples, all the sites are in Beta except Chemistry.SE, so I think it could be added but there is also a close reason that states *"General chemistry questions are off topic...."* and redirects the OP to Chem.SE

A [similar question](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/why-cant-i-select-any-site-i-want-when-i-vote-to-close-a-question?r=SearchResults) was also asked before.